# Responsive columns not adding up..?

Tags: css

I'm creating columns based on percentages. For example, I have two columns 50%. These should add up to 100% and fit on the same row.

`.col_half { width: 50%; display:inline-block; }`

However, with this the second column is pushed over to the next row for some reason. If I reduce the width to 49.5%, then the two columns fit together.

The same problem with three columns, if I set it to 33.3%, the last column gets pushed over. If I reduce it to 32.8%, they all fit. In both cases, there's a small gap on the right side of the width, since they don't add up exactly to 100%.

These columns are all in a row with width set to 100%. I'm wondering what could be causing this issue? I'm using Bootstrap, which maybe affecting it..?

Comment: This is not a WP issue but rather a CSS issue. Your problem is that the container content is sized and it's margin/border being excluded. Have a look at `box-sizing` CSS style.

Answer (score 0):

If two division or other block level elements have 50% `width` and `float` they will appear next to each other. If you don't have `float` add `float: left;` to both elements. If you have `float: left;` and `width: 50%;` specified for both elements then child content is overflowing. Use Firebug's DOM inspector to start removing child elements from these parent elements until the layout is fixed and then you'll know where to move on to in order to rectify the situation.

Answer (score 0):

When two (or more) corresponding elements have `position: inline-block`, all *white-spaces* between their ending/starting tags are affecting the space between them in HTML. The only way to avoid this is to remove all *white-spaces* between those elements yet in the text editor, like this:

```
<div>
    blah blah
</div><div>
    blah2 blah2
</div>
```

instead of this

```
<div>
    blah blah
</div><!-- Here is white-space (new line) -->
<div>
    blah2 blah2
</div>
```